# How to wait for the promise to get resolved

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise, azure-function-app

I am trying to write a function inside a async function in nodejs. here is my sample script

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
   var mydata = (async () => {
     return "output needed"
   }) ()
  
   console.log(mydata)
}
```

Expected Output is : `output needed`

What I get is : `promise{ <pending> }`

Any Idea to wait till the promise is fulfilled?

Comment: everything looks synchronous. remove sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the `Promise` returned by `mydata`:

```js
async function test(context, req) {
   var mydata = (async () => {
     return "output needed"
   }) ()
  
   console.log(await mydata)
}

test()
```